# $L^2$ function with compact support is in $L^1$?

Tags: lp-spaces

I'm reading Real analysis(Stein) and confused by a statement:
If $f\in L^2$, then $f\chi_R$ is in both $L^1$ and $L^2$, where $\chi_R$ is the characteristic function of $[-R, R]$.

But $f$ in $L^2$ does not mean that $f\in L^1$. Such an example given by [Almost everywhere continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666590/almost-everywhere-continuous-functions). How could this function on $[-R, R]$ be in $L^1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
\|f\chi_R\|_1 \leq \|f\|_2\|\chi_R\|_2 = (2R)^{1/2}\|f\|_2 < \infty.
$$

Comment: Oh thank u!! I must be confused by that example.

Comment: @RussellHiwayor The example shows only that there are nonmeasurable functions whose square is measurable. Such a function will not be in $L^2$ because $L^2$ consists of all measurable functions that are square integrable. However, this isn't the main point. There are elements in $L^2$ that are not in $L^1$, but on a finite measure space (which is what we are really working with by multiplying by $\chi_R$), then $L^p \subseteq L^q$ for all $p>q$. To prove this statement, just use Holder's inequality as I have used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality here.